# React escapes already escaped string

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, xss

I have an app that uses Express + mongoose as its backend, and React as its frontend. On the backend, the validation of user input is done by `express-validator` the following way:

```js
body('text')
      .trim()
      .escape()
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .withMessage('Comment should contain something, right?'),
```

The mongoose model schema:

```js
const commentSchema = new Schema<IComment>({
  author: String,
  post: {
    type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post',
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
  },
  date: Date,
});
```

The `text` and `author` properties are what I have trouble with. I made sure the data comes to the backend unescaped, and from the backend it comes escaped (and only once, by `express-validator`). However, when I try to render in React a string coming from the backend like `that's the` (it contains `'` character), it's rendered in the browser as `that&#x27;s the`. When I inspected the element, I found that the ampersand has been replaced with `&amp`, and the string ended up being displayed exactly the way it came from the backend. It appears that the ampersand was doubly escaped. **Is there a way to prevent this without installing any external libraries and using dangerouslySetInnerHTML?** I just don't want this ampersand to be escaped. My assumption is that it's done by React.
The component has the following structure:

```
   <Wrapper>
      <Author>{author}</Author>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
      <Date>{date}</Date>
    </Wrapper>
```

Same happens if I insert all the values in a plain `<div>`.

---

EDIT: If I hardcode something like `&lt;html&gt;` right into the JSX tag, everything works fine. If I hardcode `{"&lt;html&gt;"}`, this is treated as a string and is escaped. The data coming from the backend is, well, string, but already escaped.

Comment: Why does your back-end escape strings? It's not its job to escape UI things.

Comment: You can create a div, set the backend's text as .innerHTML, then get the div's .innerText: https://jsfiddle.net/wef6qn8m/ But I'd store text unescaped in the backend instead.

Comment: @YuriyYakym The input is a comment. Backend processes it and saves. Then, the client fetches comments and displays them. If the data was escaped only by the client, wouldn't it be possible to bypass it and perform an XSS attack?

Comment: @ChrisG Are you sure it's safe?

Comment: As you said, React already escapes. That's because afaik it uses innerText to insert text, precisely to prevent inserting arbitrary HTML.

Comment: Try inserting a comment like `<script>alert("hello")</script>`. It will appear in text form and not run.

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah, I know it will escape it. I was just wondering whether it's possible to bypass it. Maybe, with writing some additional javascript in browser console. But it now seems to me it's only possible to inject javascript into your own browser tab this way, not into the ones that other users have, because all the data *they* render is rendered with escaping by react.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just send plain unescaped strings from back-end.
It should be front-end who decides how to render and whether to escape the data, and unless you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` you are safe.

Let's say somebody has written a comment containing xss script. You can save the comment in a database as is, and then React will automatically escape it for you, so that script will never be evaluated (again, unless you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render the comment).

Comment: It's not me who downvoted the answer. I upvoted it because it seems reasonable. But am I right to understand that it's impossible in this case to prevent double escaping and that I have to rely on React only?

Comment: @i.lamanosau you should rely on React only, since there is no need in additional manipulations.

Comment: If you really want, the only solution is to unescape escaped string before rendering, like so `<div>{unescape(escapedString)}</div>`. It's still safe, because React will escape it back again. But I wouldn't do it this way, since it is redundant, quite dirty and breaks POLA.

Comment: Your answer was extremely short and didn't address OP's question directly. Recommending to store unescaped text in the backend is fine (and what I did, too) but strictly speaking not an answer, given that there is an actual way to do this. It's ultimately up to OP. Also, this is [very likely a duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+insert+escaped+text+without+dangerouslysetinnerhtml+site%3Astackoverflow.com) because every question is.